# How can I propagate exceptions from asyncio functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio, and I have noticed that exception do not get raised within async functions.

I have created a sample of the problem I am facing, where my async function looks like:

```py
async def async_fun(foo):
    try:
        get_foo = await some_thing_async(bar)
    except Exception as E:
        raise E  # Does not raise exception :(
```

Which I gather and run like:

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(async_fun("baz"), return_exceptions=True)


asyncio.run(main())
```

How can I propagate exceptions from `async_fun`? I want to be able to raise exceptions if they occur. Happy to provide further information if needed.

Comment: try
loop = asycio.get_event_loop()
group = asyncio.gather(async_fun("baz"), return_exceptions=True)
loop.run_until_complete(group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return_exceptions=True` explicitly tells `asyncio.gather()` to *return* exceptions raised by awaitables, instead of propagating them which is the default behavior. Since you don't examine the return value of `asyncio.gather()`, you have no way of noticing the exceptions.

To fix the issue, just remove `return_exceptions=True` from the invocation of `asyncio.gather`:

```
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(async_fun("baz"))
```

Also note that if you only await one function, `asyncio.gather` is unnecessary, so the above could have been written more shortly as `await async_fun("baz")`.